# Simple Select query returning zero rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying this simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE MATCH (`User`) AGAINST ('User') LIMIT 5
```

I have a FULLTEXT index on column User.

EXPLAIN SELECT returns:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  Users   fulltext    user_comparator user_comparator 0       1   Using where
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should give us the data you are working on. It just looks like there is no City containing Pilar. However, I assume City is just the name of the City, you shouldn't use MATCH .. AGAINST but use the equality operator (`WHERE City = 'Pilar'`)

Comment: I changed the query so there are no confusions, I need to use match I think in case the search term is a substring. However I tried with a simple operator and didn't return any results. There are however rows with City = Pilar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if 50% or more of your column `user` has the phrase 'User' in it, it would be considered common and would not match any rows. if you are dealing with a small amount of data you could always use the 'like' comparator.

Comment: that was it. I had too few users, adding a few fixed the issue